Why does `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` fail to find a file unless I specify a lower-level directory to search from?
I get three results from this command:
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ -Recurse -Filter sshd_config

    Directory: C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          21/12/2022    14:18           3115 sshd_config

    Directory: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\etc\ssh

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          09/06/2024    10:10           3116 sshd_config

    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\etc\ssh

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          17/02/2024    14:33           3116 sshd_config

But if I start the search in a child directory, I find the file I was looking for (missing from the previous results):
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ProgramData -Recurse -Filter sshd_config

    Directory: C:\ProgramData\ssh

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          06/05/2022    15:15           2297 sshd_config

Does anyone have an explanation for why this is?

ProgramData is a hidden folder :) you would need to use -Force so the cmdlet traverses hidden folders

Yes, this is the answer. Thanks!

As commented by https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon, the answer was to include the -Force flag in order to also search hidden folders.
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ -Recurse -Force -Filter sshd_config
